# Beginning with Swing Layouts

Tags: java, swing

I'm a web developer and now developing a swing application. I'm using Netbeans. Currently the layouts is set as free layout. But while running too many issues are there.

What is the best suggested method to start with it? There will be multiple layers/levels of forms/options/buttons/tabs. There are many Layouts. Which Layout should I go for. I'll be using both. Netbeans + hand coding.

Comment: Actually Netbeans free layout works pretty fine if you use it right. Anyway i guess you should use different layouts depending on the requirements, at least read this [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Comment: @nidu i'm facing problems when the forms are resized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Free layout isn't good during resizing the container or manipulation (adding, removing, setting visible/invisible) of components placed in the frames (or other containers). Using a layout manager with different kinds of layouts works perfectly giving the required blend between easy coding and personalization.

Here is the tutorial for the LayoutManager (along with further links to library classes, etc. ):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

However, you won't be able to modify the code generated by the netbeans IDE. You will have to either use handwritten code entirely or use the NetBeans generated code entirely. It can't be both.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely 3rd party for anything beyond hobby programming: while any of the Big Three (FormLayout, DesignGridLayout, MigLayout) may be fine, my personal favourite currently is [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/). For me, it has a slight edge over FormLayout in a more intuitive handling of padding and less problems in the layout of cell-spanning components.

Just as definitely hand-coding - in my experience, the vendor lock-in of a visual builder will bite you sooner than you can image ...

My 2 (Euro :-) cents only, of course, mileage varies.

Comment: +1 especially if the user is a beginner in Swing. In the end, coding manually Swing interfaces always end up with better code and better UI.

Answer (score 1):

For forms I strongly suggest the 3th party [`FormLayout` (of JGoodies)](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/)

Answer (score 0):

The layout you should use really depends on what you are trying to do. That being said, maybe the [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) would be the easier to grasp and will also allow you to position your components around nicely.

Since you also mention that you will have lots of forms, you can also take a look at the
[CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). This will allow you to use the same frame to display different content.